# Ubuntu not shutting off

Tags: power-management, restart

So I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it won't shut down after updating, I have to manually shut it down by holding the power key, it happens when I either try to restart it or shut it down. Anyone got any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: until you find a permanent solution you may be able to use Sudo telinit 0 or sudo halt to shutdown you system

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to shutdown with the shutdown command from a terminal?

1. Open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `sudo shutdown -h now` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. This should now shut down the computer/laptop
4. If it does not, then it should output something on the terminal window
5. Do a search on the error on AskUbuntu

Hope this helps :-)